# How to parallelize a ST_Union(geom) GROUP BY X statement in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Imagine that I have the following PostgreSQL table.

```
state         county        county_geom
Arizona       Pima          SRID=4326;MULTIPOLYGON(((40.9834..))
Arizona       Cochise       SRID=4326;MULTIPOLYGON(((40.9834..))
Wisconsin     Dane          SRID=4326;MULTIPOLYGON(((40.9834..))
Wisconsin     Sauk          SRID=4326;MULTIPOLYGON(((40.9834..))
```

I want to create a new table with the union of the geometries of each county for each state. The appropriate SQL statement would be as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE NewTable AS SELECT state, ST_Union(county_geom) AS state_geom FROM MyTable GROUP BY state;
```

I would like this process to be parallelized such that one state (e.g., Arizona) is unioned on one node/core/worker while other states (e.g., Wisconsin) are unioned on other nodes/cores/workers.

This [blog link](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2016/03/parallel-postgis.html) indicates that the aggregate function `ST_Union` cannot currently be parallelized. However, I do not think that the aggregate function needs to run in parallel, so much as the different groups (e.g., states) need to be distributed.

Is there a parameter that can be added to the above statement to make it operate in parallel, or is there a completely different formulation of the above statement that would work in parallel?

EDIT: I am not looking for a solution that involves using an outside scripting language (e.g., python) to parallelize the process. I already know how to do this. I'm trying work on this entirely in the PostgreSQL environment.

Comment: I was gonna say, open multiple connections and use each connection for each state but you say that is not what you want. Other trick could be to JOIN with county geom from different table instead of doing ST_Union to circumvent parallel restriction, maybe.